# SQLiteDatabase transformar retorno em json

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, apache-cordova

Boa tarde, preciso fazer uma query porém não posso usar o cursor.

Exemplo eu tenho um objeto que criei que se chama DatabaseHelper, dentro dele criei alguns métodos (prepare,bindParam,getQuery,execute), porém no execute eu preciso que o retorno seja um JSONArray ou um array como é feito no PHP com o mysql. Seque abaixo um exemplo do que eu estou tentando fazer. Tenho essa necessidade porque a query será executada via JavaScript em uma aplicação ApacheCordova, porém não posso usar o cursor.

```
@JavascriptInterface
public JSONObject execute() throws JSONException{
    String sql = this.sql_prepare;
    JSONObject retorno = new JSONObject();
    try
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(sql);

        retorno.put("ok", true);
        retorno.put("return", "Aqui deve conter um objeto array para que eu possa trabalhar com o javascript e esse objeto deve conter todo o retorno do execSQL");
        return retorno;
    } catch(Exception e){

        AlertDialog.Builder erro = new AlertDialog.Builder(contexto);
        erro.setTitle("Erro de SQL");
        erro.setMessage("Ocorreu um erro na execução de sua query.\nQuery: "+sql+"\nErro:"+e.getMessage());
        erro.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        erro.show();

        retorno.put("ok", false);
        retorno.put("return", e.getMessage().toString());
        return retorno;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, para isso não podes usar [`execSQL (String sql)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29):

> **execSQL(String sql)**
> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.

Que traduzido:

> **execSQL(String sql)**
> Executar uma única instrução SQL que não é uma instrução SELECT ou qualquer outra instrução SQL que retorna dados.

---

## arrayList a partir de consulta à BD

Gerar um `arrayList` a partir de uma consulta à base de dados:

```
public ArrayList<String> GetAllValues(String aTable,String[] aColumn)
{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(aTable, aColumn, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) 
    {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return list;
}
```

**Nota:** Para obteres todas as colunas, passa `null` no parametro `aColumn`.

<sup>Exemplo retirado desta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6854192/352449) do @Khawar no SOEN.</sup>

---

## Objeto JSON a partir de arrayList

Para a questão do *JSON*, podes fazer uso da classe [`JSONObject`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) para converter os dados resultantes da tua consulta no *JSON*.

**Exemplo**

```
// Novo objecto JSON
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

// Consulta BD
ArrayList<DrugDetails> drugDetails = DataInterface
            .getSelectedDrugDetails(); //isto deve ser a consulta que devolve um arraylist

// Se temos dados
if (drugDetails != null && drugDetails.size() > 0) {

    // Novo array para guardar as entradas do JSON
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

    // Por cada entrada da BD, adiciona uma entrada no JSON
    for (DrugDetails selectedDrugDetails : drugDetails) {

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put(APPOINTMENT_ID, ""+"selectedDrugDetails.getAppoinmentID()");
        json.put(DOCUMENT_ID, ""+selectedDrugDetails.getId());
        array.put(json);
    }

    jsonObject.put(COLLATERAL_LIST, array);
}
```

<sup>Exemplo retirado desta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16833566/352449) do @srikanthgr no SOEN.</sup>

Comment: Desculpa não entendi a parte do Consulta BD

Comment: @HiagoSouza Um método qualquer teu onde efetivamente consultas a base de dados e devolves para esse código de exemplo um `ArrayList` com os dados selecionados.

Comment: Então mais a minha pergunta foi exatamente essa, como que eu pego o retorno de um select e transformo em um arraylist para colocar no jsonobject.

Comment: @HiagoSouza Já completei a resposta com um exemplo para esse caso de gerar um `arrayList` a partir da consulta realizada à base de dados.

Comment: Obrigado, agora conssigo prosseguir ;)